# Creeper blew me into space (?). Can't see anything. How do I get back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Creeper got the drop on me. I'm in space (I guess). All I can see are the sun, the stars and the moon. Single player survival mode. I can move, i.e., avatar makes walking motions, but the scenery doesn't change.

I tried reloading several times and running the game from the website, with no effect.

Comment: Are you still? Or does your character seem to be falling? (Sometimes I experienced something similar when the game didn't load the appropriate chunks correctly. Have you tried turning it off and on again?)

Comment: One word. SPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCCCEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE. (it had do be said).

Comment: Hit F3.  What are your XYZ coordinates?

Comment: Are you willing to use cheats/external tools to return, if necessary?

Comment: Have you tried copying your World and logging into the copy?

Comment: Are you talking about the .dat file?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds as though you're in [the Void](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Void).  That usually kills you, however, which makes me suspect you're using mods.  If you happen to be using Single Player Commands, you can use the `/home` command to warp back to your bed or spawn point.

If not, you're likely stuck with using an external tool.  In particular, I know that [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-18/) has the ability to set the player's current location.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't see the sun and moon in the void. You might be able to pre-1.8 though. Otherwise, it's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs — The sky actually *is* the Void.  When in the Void, you can see the sun or moon (whichever has risen) normally.  This is easily visible in maps like Skyblock.

Comment: I could see BOTH the sun and the moon. There was no cycle. Wasn't using any mods. I was aware of Single Player Commands and was about to use it. However, I moved around a bit more and ended up falling in the ocean, almost 2 kilometers from my spawn point. o.O

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @not sure — Very odd, but I'm glad to hear you got home safely!  If you took screenshots, I'd love to see them.

Comment: MCEdit is the solution